# How to note that I worked for company's supplier on resume?

Tags: resume, hardware

The title pretty much says it all. I'm creating a resume to apply for a large company "A." My last job was at company "B," a small, but high-quality supplier of components for company A. It is likely that those handling my resume won't have heard of company B, but given that I would be working in similar fields at both companies (radio-frequency electrical engineering), I think it might be relevant to mention, on the resume, that I worked for a component supplier of company A.

At company A, I would be working with radio systems. At company B, I helped design high-end crystal oscillators (a component of radio systems), which we supplied to company A. In the past, company B has been a "preferred supplier" of company A (a designation handed out by company A), and I believe that there is generally good will between the two companies.

I also believe I personally helped work on parts for company A, but I don't recall for certain.

How do I best draw attention to the connection between these two companies? Or should I not mention it? My current best thought is simply putting, "Worked with a [company A] supplier designing and manufacturing crystal oscillators," or something of the like, but I don't know if that would inadvertently give a bad impression or be tacky, although (in my opinion) relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I best draw attention to the connection between these two
> companies?

Use your cover letter to draw attention to this fact, not your resume.

Explain the connection, and why it makes you particularly well suited for the position. Make sure to mention that your current company is a preferred supplier - that's a good thing.

> I also believe I personally helped work on parts for company A, but I
> don't recall for certain.

Leave that out, unless you can be certain.

Comment: Thank you for the actionable alternative to putting the information on a resume. This company doesn't accept cover letters, but I'll likely bring it up in any interview.

Comment: I guess, more accurately, there wasn't a place to enter one on the application form.

Comment: There was just one place to upload a single file, designated for the resume. I've put in the applications now, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you simply list your last employer as company B and its location on your resume. Then, you can briefly describe the work you did for company B on your resume also.

When the hiring managers from company A read your resume, they will instantly recognize company B, and the relationship between the 2 companies along with your projects you did for company B. If they interview you, they will ask you for more details about your skills and experiences at company B.

Comment: I talked with other engineers in the new company (friends), and they didn't seem to know my old company, so I doubt HR would. This still might be the best approach, though.

Comment: You're probably correct that HR wouldn't get it, but HR isn't the same as the hiring manager. If you're looking for ways to get past generic HR screening, who knows what helps with that. Your prior experience might be truly helpful, but generic screening mechanisms often ignore things they should actually consider. Instead, if goal is to get noticed by hiring manager, then adding to your cover letter and/or resume can be helpful.